Finger counting using hand tracking: tuple index out of range: what causes this?
I'm following the video of Murtaza's Workshop - Robotics and AI (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p5Z_GGRCI5s&ab_channel=Murtaza%27sWorkshop-RoboticsandAI)
and I get an error:
INFO: Created TensorFlow Lite XNNPACK delegate for CPU.
([], [])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\thepr\PycharmProjects\pythonProject2\finger.py", line 22, in <module>
    if lmList[tipIds[id]][2] < lmList[tipIds[id] - 2][2]:
       ~~~~~~^^^^^^^^^^^^
IndexError: tuple index out of range

Process finished with exit code 1

This is my code:
import cv2
import time

from cvzone.HandTrackingModule import HandDetector
##import HandTrackingModule as htm

wcam, hcma = 640 ,480
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
cap.set(3, wcam)
cap.set(4, hcma)
pTime = 0
detector = HandDetector(detectionCon=0.7, maxHands=5)
tipIds = [4,8,12,16,20]
while True:
    sccuess, img = cap.read()
    img = detector.findHands(img)
    lmList = detector.findPosition(img, draw=False)
    print(lmList)
    if len(lmList) != 0:
        fingers = []
        for id in range (0,5):
           if lmList[tipIds[id]][2] < lmList[tipIds[id] - 2][2]:
               fingers.append(1)
           else:
               fingers.append(0)


    cTime = time.time()
    fps = 1 / (cTime - pTime)
    pTime = cTime
    cv2.putText(img,f'fps: {int(fps)}',(70,40), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN,3,(255,255,0),3)
    cv2.imshow("imgge",img)
    cv2.waitKey(1)

Why do I get this error, when I have followed the instructions from the video?
i tried something new from gpt and
new error
[]
[]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\thepr\PycharmProjects\pythonProject2\finger.py", line 21, in <module>
    if lmList[8][2] < lmList[6][2]:
       ~~~~~~~~~^^^
IndexError: list index out of range
[[207, 319], [256, 314], [297, 291], [320, 262], [342, 238], [278, 215], [300, 174], [314, 150], [326, 129], [250, 201], [268, 155], [281, 128], [293, 107], [221, 200], [232, 153], [242, 126], [253, 104], [191, 209], [189, 169], [192, 144], [198, 121]]

Process finished with exit code 1

changed code
    if len(lmList)!=0 :
        fingers = []
        for id in range(0, 5):
            if lmList[tipIds[id]][2] < lmList[tipIds[id] - 2][2]:
                fingers.append(1)
            else:
                fingers.append(0)
    else:
        fingers = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]  # Default value when lmList does not have enough elements```



Think of Stack Overflow like a FAQ, not a forum. Your question title should describe a specific technical problem as clearly as possible.

It is most likely the lmlist does not have enough, or any, items in it. What does it show on the printed line?

@OldBoy, the printed line was present in the  code block: ([], []). I have put it at the top so it is easier to see what the generated output is.

Looking at the source of HandTrackingModule.py here:
https://github.com/cvzone/cvzone/blob/master/cvzone/HandTrackingModule.py
it seems HandDetector doesnt have a findPosition method.
Are you certain that you've shared the right code, and all of it? As provided it shouldn't run at all

It looks like lmlist does not contain any information, which is the reason for the error. You need to find out why the call to detector.findPosition did not return anything.

'
[]
[[263, 437], [187, 396], [138, 327], [117, 262], [90, 210], [203, 223], [191, 137], [191, 85], [196, 41], [255, 217], [251, 123], [252, 65], [255, 15], [302, 232], [311, 146], [318, 94], [325, 49], [348, 264], [371, 202], [383, 163], [394, 124]]
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\thepr\PycharmProjects\pythonProject2\finger.py", line 22, in 
if lmList[tipIds[id]][2] < lmList[tipIds[id] - 2][2]:
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^^^
IndexError: list index out of range
Process finished with exit code 1'
it printed this after some blank and same error

"tried something from gpt": What is that "something"? Please make sure to provide the code with which you get this new error message.

added the new coded that i used from it sorry it copied the wrong one

To be clear: are you asking what an IndexError means, or how to understand what the code is trying to do? Or are you asking why the list contains something different from what you expected? In the first case, I'm happy to close this as a duplicate so that you can get a high quality explanation. Otherwise, we need a more detailed investigation on your part - try to create a [mre] of the problem, not just the overall code for the task you want to solve. We should be able to clearly see exactly what you think should happen differently, step by step, and why you think it should be that way.

"Please fix my code" is not what Stack Overflow is for, and "please fix ChatGPT's code" (or "...some code I copied off the screen from a Youtube video"), doubly so.

I think most of this problem is coming from using a library that changed its interface at least two times and so the return value of methods is not of the same type as expected.

@trincot given your attempt, that makes sense; but this looks very much like the start of a chameleon question.

I agree. I will not pursue this further, as this will be a cascade of "and now I have this error", and "after applying your fix, there is now this problem", ... and it will never stop.

im following the video and according to it i was supposed to get like a continuous output of all the fingers that im using it should show like [1,1,1,1,1] or any closed one but it is not showing and its getting closed one it detect any fingers
empty loop and then when shown fingers process ends

I'm just going to apply the duplicate anyway and let others sort it out, honestly. If that doesn't answer OP's question then whatever the actual question is, is not suitable for Stack Overflow. We don't provide a debugging service here.

well its a learning phase and tbh i wouldnt ask here but i couldnt find and understand as it was hard to get the library to run in the begining and i appreciate for all the help i can do rnd on my own but just wanted to know as learning

@Yash, did you understand what I wrote above? The video is using a different version of cv2 module, as it shows a different structure of return data type. That is not your fault, but it means that if you load the latest version of the module, the same code will not run correctly. You'll have to find out which version of the module to load, how to get it, where to find it, or else find how to do it with the newer version -- which will be different from what the video shows. The video is 3 years old. A lot changes in three years.

yess i understood and did added the same library he had but ill debug on won and look into it

You do understand that you are not using the same (version) of that library? Do you notice how yours returns a tuple, and the video's a list? Do understand this implies you're not using the same?

It looks like you're using a previous version of the cv2 library, which still had the findPosition method (See here). But when looking at what you get as output (([], [])), and how that method is used here in a basic example:
lmList, bbox = detector.findPosition(img)

...and also how it is used in this Stack Overflow question, it looks like you should not assign the returned value to lmList, but assign the first tuple member to lmList.
So change this line:
lmList = detector.findPosition(img, draw=False)

to:
lmList,_ = detector.findPosition(img, draw=False)

I guess the video was made with a still earlier version of the module, where the return value was just the list, as we can clearly see in the video the output of a list, not a tuple of two lists, like you are getting. The above change should overcome that difference.

'[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[[263, 437], [187, 396], [138, 327], [117, 262], [90, 210], [203, 223], [191, 137], [191, 85], [196, 41], [255, 217], [251, 123], [252, 65], [255, 15], [302, 232], [311, 146], [318, 94], [325, 49], [348, 264], [371, 202], [383, 163], [394, 124]]
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\thepr\PycharmProjects\pythonProject2\finger.py", line 22, in 
if lmList[tipIds[id]][2] < lmList[tipIds[id] - 2][2]:
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^^^
IndexError: list index out of range
Process finished with exit code 1'
still same

It's not the same. Your list is different and the error occurs after a few iterations. But due to formatting I cannot interpret the error well. Please add it to your question in an additional section.

added it im sorrry about it

The cv2 library has changed through time, not providing backwards compatibility, and that's why you are having problems. I have tried to pinpoint a problem, but there seem to be more than one. But you can do this investigation yourself, so I will leave it at this: just look at the output you get and see how it is different from the video. Find out which version of the module you are using, etc, etc. It is tedious, but you'll learn more from it than this ping-pong.
